# Components of pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

According to the theory, hydrostatic pressure acts in the direction normal to the surface. Accordingly, for a profile of a wall in the shape of a quarter circle (as shown in the attached diagram), the horizontal component at the deepest point is considered to be 0. However, I see calculations online suggesting that hydrostatic pressure can be analyzed horizontally as an increasing force from the water surface (see the attached diagram), implying that at the same point, the horizontal component has a maximum value. Therefore, these two interpretations seem contradictory to me. Can you explain why this works this way?

[image: wall]

[image: components]

Comment: The pressure is in all directions, what is normal is the net force on an object in contact with the water. If you modify the shape of the object the direction of the force will change, but not the pressure.

Comment: Also helpful: Pressure is a scalar, and force is a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressure exerts a normal force but not a tangential force (sometimes referred to as traction).

So there’s no contradiction between one example with a (horizontal) tangential force of zero and another example with a (horizontal) normal force that’s not zero.

The orientation of the surfaces in the two examples is different, and a stress field (such as hydrostatic pressure) always involves a coupling between force vectors and surface orientation vectors; the latter can’t be ignored.